# Show that distribution of statistic is independent of parameter

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Consider a random sample of size $n$ froma  gamma distribution, $X_i\sim GAM(\theta, \kappa)$, and let $\bar X=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum X_i$ and $\tilde X=(\prod X_i)^{1/n}$ be the sample mean and geometric mean, respectively.
>
> **Show that the distribution of $T=\bar X/\tilde X$ does not depend on $\theta$.**

It can be shown easily that $\bar X$ and $\tilde X$ are jointly complete and sufficient statistics for $\theta$ and $\kappa$.  I'm not necessarily sure if that will help me with this, but I don't really know how to go about this.  Surely I don't need to use bivariate transformation, do I?  There's got to be an easier way to show this than that.  Any ideas?

Comment: It may just be my eyesight or screen resolution, but in the question the tilde in $\tilde{X}$ looks very like the bar in $\bar{X}$, though in this comment they look different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\deq{\stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{=}}$Suppose $Y_1, \cdots, Y_n$ are i.i.d. such that $Y_k \sim {\mit Γ}(1, κ)$, then$$
(X_1, \cdots, X_n) \deq (θY_1, \cdots, θY_n).
$$
So$$
(\overline{X}, \widetilde{X}) = \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n X_k, \left( \prod_{k = 1}^n X_k \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \right) \deq \left( θ \cdot \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n Y_k, θ \cdot \left( \prod_{k = 1}^n Y_k \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \right) = (θ \overline{Y},θ \widetilde{Y}),$$
where$$
\overline{Y} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n Y_k,\ \widetilde{Y} = \left( \prod_{k = 1}^n Y_k \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}.
$$
Thus$$
\frac{\overline{X}}{\widetilde{X}} \deq \frac{\overline{Y}}{\widetilde{Y}},
$$
which does not depend on $θ$.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks.