# Conditional Distribution from Gamma Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

> Consider a random sample of size $n$ froma  gamma distribution, $X_i\sim GAM(\theta, \kappa)$, with $\kappa$ being the shape parameter and $\theta$ being the scale parameter and let $\bar X=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum X_i$ and $\tilde X=(\prod X_i)^{1/n}$ be the sample mean and geometric mean, respectively.
>
> **Show that the conditional distribution of $\bar X |_{\tilde X = \tilde x}$ does not depend on $\kappa$.**

I have absolutely no idea how to find this conditional distribution.  Even if there are some strategies to go about solving this problem without solving for the conditional distribution explicitly, I don't know what they are.  How would you show this?  Is there a general strategy for finding conditional distributions of statistics that I don't know about?  I'm so lost.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675867/show-that-distribution-of-statistic-is-independent-of-parameter)

Comment: @zhoraster could you elaborate on how to use the observation that $\bar{X}/\tilde{X}$ does not depend on the scale parameter $\theta$ to conclude that the conditional distribution of $\bar{X}$ given $\tilde{X}=\tilde{x}$  does not depend on the shape parameter $\kappa$?

Comment: @Martin It's true, the questions are different.  That question could have been useful if the actual distribution of the ratio was known; but it's not, so I don't have anything to work with to calculate the conditional distribution.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked the fact that you're looking at a different parameter.

Comment: @zhoraster.  Yeah, the fact that it's the shape parameter instead of the scale really has me stumped.

Comment: Anyway. For fixed (known) $\theta$, prove that $X_1\cdots X_n$ is a sufficient statistic, which immediately gives the result.

Comment: @zhoraster, I'm sorry, I'm not quite following.  I don't understand how showing that the product is sufficient shows that the ratio is independent of the scale parameter.

Comment: *Shape* parameter, you mean? And why ratio? We're talking about sample mean, not ratio. Anyway, this does not matter at all. Sufficiency of $T$, by definition, means that the distribution of the sample given $T$ is independent of the parameter. Then, obviously, the same is true for any function of the sample: sample mean, sample variance, $X_1$ etc.